# Spring MVC - Selective Formatting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a custom tag that extends Spring's `InputTag` to display numbers in the format `",###.0"`. I've registered a custom `PropertyEditor` for the `Double` class to handle the formatting.

When a form is submitted and validation fails, all invalid values should be re-displayed as-is, without any formatting, so that the user can see the mistake he made. How do I inform the custom tag of the validation result so that it does not do any formatting?

I'm using Spring MVC 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `getPropertyEditor()` method of `AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag`, and return null instead of `PropertyEditor` instance (so the `ValueFormatter` will not pass the object value to `PropertyEditor` for formatting purpose).

```
public class CustomInputTag extends InputTag {
@Override
protected PropertyEditor getPropertyEditor() throws JspException {
    if(getBindStatus().getErrors().hasErrors()) {
        return null;
    }
    return super.getPropertyEditor();
   }
}
```